# How to add rows in pandas with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Maybe someone knows how to add two rows of an data frame by grouping with specific condition.

```
dfa.groupby(['Col1','Col2'])[['Quantity']].sum()
```

Say we have this df:

```
  Col1  Col2 Quantity
0  1     1     10 
1  1     1     10
2  2     1     3
3  1     2     3
4  1     2     3
```

And Im trying to get this:
Condition to sum: 
Col1 element of one Row is equal to element of other row in Col1 AND
Col2 element of that Row is equal to element of the other row in Col2

```
  Col1  Col2 Quantity
0  1     1     20 
2  2     1     3
3  1     2     6
```

Comment: The expression you mentioned works perfectly for me. What error are you getting?

Comment: @Phani: I posted one example where it does not meet the condition

Comment: Can you update it with result as well. Also it would be great if you can add code to reproduce this data frame.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like what you are looking for:

```
dfa[dfa.Col1 == dfa.Col2].groupby(['Col1','Col2'])[['Quantity']].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think that Groupby would do the trick.

Comment: I posted how groupby would fail to meet the condition in other example im working with.

Comment: So you want to group by Col1, Col2 and sum Money where those codes(C,D,E,etc) are the same as well as the names?

Comment: thanks for the support. It should sum money where Col1 and Col2 are equal. Please forget the Column codes (C,D,E etc) and the column Names(Antonia, Jose etc). I will correct my question now.

Comment: Ok, Groupby will do exactly what you want.  It will only sum Money where Col1 AND Col2 are equal

Comment: Nevermind, Hangon.  I think i understand what you mean now. I believe user1827356 has your answer

Comment: Thanks Bob. Great help!